# Caesar cipher code in c

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

I have been working on this Caesar cipher code and this is what I have gotten so far and when the program runs nothing happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 80

 main()
{
    int shift, num; 
    char ciph[MAX];
    printf("Enter the message to be encrypted: ");
    while ((ciph[num] = getchar()) != '\n'){  //loops until a blank space is read
        for(num=0; num<MAX; num++){ //scans characters into the array
        ciph[num] = getchar();
        }
    }
    printf("\nEnter the shift amout: ");
    scanf("%d", &shift); //reads the shift amount
    for (num = 0; num < MAX; num++) //shifts the letter
    {
        int c = ciph[num];
        if ('a' >= c && c <= 'z')
            c = ((c - 'a') + shift) % 26 + 'a';
        else if ('A' >= c && c <= 'Z')
            c = ((c - 'A') + shift) % 26 + 'A';
        else
        {

    }
    ciph[num] = c;
}
printf("%c", ciph[num]); //prints the encryption
}
```

Comment: What is your input?  80 keystrokes?  Suspect code should detect `'\n'` in the first loop.

Comment: how should i incorporate that?

Comment: Curious, I requested what input OP used (to help better understand the goal) and instead of a sample input, OP replied with a request for more help.

Comment: my bad, i dont know what op is but im gonna assume you are referring to me. but anyways 80 is the max amount of characters that will be stored into the array, the input is letters.

Comment: `char ciph[10]` is a string, for example "test". `chip[0]` is one character in that string, in this case `t`. Use gets or scanf to get the input `chip`. User `printf("%s\n", chip)` to print the string. `printf("%c", chip[num])` will only print one character. Also `num` must be initialized to zero.

Comment: How will anyone learn from this incident if you delete the question content after you discover your error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your intent is but

```
'a' <= ciph
```

needs to be

```
'a' <= ciph[SOMETHING]
```

and

```
ciph = (ciph - 'a')+shift) % 26 + 'a';
```

is missing a '('

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to leave the blank space alone with this thing, but I guess that's up to you.

```
//read the whole line

int i;
int len = strlen(line);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    int c = line[i];
    if ('a' >= c && c <= 'z')
        c = ((c - 'a') + shift) % 26 + 'a';
    else if ('A' >= c && c <= 'Z')
        c = ((c - 'A') + shift) % 26 + 'A';
    else
    {
        //leave it
    }
    line[i] = c;
}

//write the whole line
```

Comment: why did you make an int with the value of ciph couldnt i have left it?

Comment: @Isaiah, I meant you can work on the whole string, instead of asking user to input one character at a time. I changed the code again, I renamed it to `line` that's the input string

Comment: oh i see, but 1 input at a time was never the goal, I'm just a newb to this i really meant to read and entire string of characters in and one by one shift them

Comment: Note: Say the length of the string was 50.  `for (i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++)` calculates the string length 50 times when 1 would do.  Suggest calculate the length outside the loop.  A simple solution is `for (i = strlen(line); i-- > 0; )`

Comment: Im not calculating, what i actually want to do is to shift the letters as the int i increments until i reaches n - 1 (the max 79) or there are no more characters to shift

Comment: @chux, noted, that's a bad habit, I shouldn't pass it on. Isaiah, I think chux was talking about my code (which I changed now). You should use gets(ciph); to get input.

Comment: ` while (ciph[num] !='\n' ){  //loops until next line is read
  for(num=0; num<MAX; num++){ //scans characters into the array
  ciph[num] = getchar();
  } this is what i used to read the letters `